# How to speed up row deleting function in Google App Script

Tags: optimization, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to run through a few hundred rows of data and delete rows that have 0 in both C and D. Deleting the ones that match that case seems to be working, but it really takes its time getting through. I'm a neophyte at scripting (I'm not a programmer, just trying to learn) and I can't figure how to make it faster. The main script came from someone else, I added the logic to do two columns and not just one. Any Ideas?

```
function deleteZeroes() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Email_Help_Total_Input');
  var range1 = s.getRange('C:C');
  var cValues = range1.getValues();
  var range2 = s.getRange('D:D');
  var dValues = range2.getValues();  

  for(var i=cValues.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(cValues[0,i]==0 && dValues[0,i]== 0) 
      s.deleteRow(i+1);

}
```

It works, but slowly. Just trying to make it a little quicker. Thanks!

Comment: The question's code isn't complete. Is it only missing the function block closing brace? Ref. [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array rather than reads and writes!

```
data = s.getDataRange().getValues();
result = [];

for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
   if (data[i][2]==0) continue; //checks C, if it finds it continues the loop
   if (data[i][3]==0) continue; //checks D, if it finds it continues the loop
   result.push(data[i]);//only those that fell through the 0 checks will be here
}
s.getDataRange().clear();
s.getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);
```

So this reads all the data at once, checks all the data and copies the good rows to a new result array, deletes the old data and then pastes back the good data. Depending on the size you should see this function in maybe 30 seconds.

Comment: Note that writing kept values is different than deleting specific rows. Consider formulas, filters, named ranges, formatting, etc

Comment: @J.G., Thank you so much for the insight! I had trouble understanding arrays, but this really helps. It works super fast, but gets rid of every instance of a 0 in Column C and Column D. The end result I'm going for is every row that has a 0 in both C and D gets deleted, every other instance stays the same. I added the logic for "and" between C and D and got the following, which worked perfectly! So the if statement looks like this now:    ```if (data[i][2]==0  && data[i][3]==0) continue;```